How do others answer the Lubavitcher Rebbe's questions on the Chanuka Miracle?
In Kuntress Mai Chanuka, the Lubavitcher Rebbe puts 3 technical requirements on the Chanuka miracle.

All 8 days should be their own miracle
The miracle should be thematic to the theme of Maccabees vs. Hellenists, and a midda k'negged midda reward for this war
The miraculous burning of the lamps of the Menora should still follow all halachot, including chumras and hiddurim.

I would like to see other sources that ask, and ideally answer, these 3 points as well i.e. how can there be a miracle that satisfies these requirements?

If the oil is made "energy dense" so it lasts 8 days, then they won't need to put in the standard minimum amount (enough to last a winter night) when (re)filling the menora cups. They will instead split it 8 ways
If the oil is made "regenerating" alá the shunamit's jugs, then it won't be made from "crushed olives" but "ex nihilo"
If the fire is "unconsuming" like the burning bush, then the oil is not being "consumed", as per the pasuk

I would be so glad to find a sefardi source that has a very similar approach to the Lubavitcher Rebbe, if such exists (and first person to bring it will likely get some bounty points from me!)

You are ideally looking for three separate sources, or one primary?

@Dr.Shmuel I have no ideals, just a thirst for knowledge

כאיל תערג על אפיקי מים

According to R' Schiffman the military victory of Chanukkah was very short lived. It ended within a year or two. Only over 25 years later because of the Syrian Greek infighting between two royal brothers, one of the sides made a treaty with the Chashmonaim heading militia force to win the throne. The result was Jewish independence of some sorts, which also forced the Chashmonaim seek a treaty with Rome to guarantee independence. Not particularly Makkabees vs. Helenists. It should be Traditional Jews vs. Helenists.

There's P'nei Yehoshua on Shabbos who says something like that by the time of Chashmonaim the miracle of Ner Tamid stopped. The Channukah miracle resembled the Ner Tamid miracle, showing that Hashem forgave the desecration done by the hellenists.

@YDJ your point is noted by the eventual sins of the Chashmonaim, however at the time of the war, they were Tzaddikim and are recorded as such for antiquity, so I will keep in that tradition and strongly recommend others to do so as well.

I do not understand this question. How are these "questions", and what kind of answers do you want?

@MichoelR see edit. This question should ideally presume that answers have read Mai Chanuka, but hopefully it's detailed enough that if there are other works that deal with these questions, people who know them will "know what I mean"

Do you think the Rebbe’s questions/assumptions came first, or is it possible that he developed an approach to Chanukah, and then used that approach to build an understanding of various parameters of the miracle, which he then presents as question-and-answer? If it’s the latter, we wouldn’t necessarily expect to see others asking these “questions”.

@JoelK his point no.1 is a very famous Beit Yosef on Chanuka

"it won't fill the requirement for the entire cup to be refilled" I've never heard of such a requirement?

"then they won't need to put in the standard minimum amount (enough to last a winter night) when (re)filling the menora cups. They will instead split it 8 ways" I don't understand why they wouldn't still be putting in the correct amount (every fuel has a different volume for burning a given time) nor why it's a problem if they wanted to put it in 8 ways or not. Who cares?

I don't understand why anyone would impose these three requirements on the miracle. We can have a fun logical game trying to work out any requirements, but what's the point?

@DoubleAA I genuinely don't see where in the question I asked for anyone to care. I just asked if any other sources ask and answer the same questions as Mai Chanuka. If you know any, great. If not, you can go ahead and learn Mai Chanuka, or you can move along

By posting your are surely hoping readers care and spend their time trying to help you find what you want. Right now I don't understand what's wrong with the "energy dense" method. If I don't understand probably others don't either. I also don't understand why you want something that satisfies some seemingly arbitrary and unfounded limitations. If I don't understand probably other don't either. Neither of these issues makes me interested to help you find an answer. If I'm not motivated probably others aren't either.

@DoubleAA I've been here a while and I have spent a lot of time helping people make good questions. Sometimes a question isn't for everyone. Mai Chanuka is a full kuntress which I can't summarise, this question is for those who know it. For those who don't, I don't expect or demand they go read it, but perhaps they might be interested enough, to give a go.

I don't know what "Mai Chanuka" is. You don't even clarify what it is. You don't say any of that. It's confusing. Maybe add a preface explaining the following is based on the content of a certain work and may not be understandable to those who haven't read it.

@DoubleAA happy to improve the question on those grounds yes. Still, you've already invalidated the question, when you said "why should we care about how a miracle should be performed, it's just a fun logical game, nothing more", so I still don't think you (or prob most) are going to be interested. When I get time, I'll improve the question

It's not invalid it's just unmotivated. Maybe there's a good reason these limitations are reasonable. If this work is as good as you seem to think it is I'd expect the author motivated the contents. Maybe there's a relevant midrashic principle or parallel.

@DoubleAA A link to the text and the table of contents have been added to the question. It provides easy access for anyone unfamiliar with the kuntress and interested in an unbiased and honest exploration of the subject. Happy Chanukah!

@RabbiKaii Without a deeper dive, my instinct concerning requirement 1 is that it probably revolves around the specific time variations for each of the 8 days of the week in the context of the hourly permutations of G-d's names. That is a kabbalistic subject discussed by Rabbi Meir Ibn Gabbai (Sephardi source) among others.

@RabbiKaii In the context of the details outlined in "Mai Chanukah" about the victory of the Makkabis over the Yavanim, you should look at the hemshech of the 3 discourses (Padah b'Shalom for 19 Kislev, for 20 Kislev and Tanu Rabbanan Nee Chanuka to parshat Mikeitz, Shabbat Chanuka) by the Rebbe according to this years cycle which coincides with Torat Menachem 5734, volume 1. In particular, the first discourse, chapter 3, page 257 and the subject of the 3 types of Jewish soul (the Intellectual Soul, the G-dly Soul , and the Animating/Animal Soul).
